# How to do enable disable in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<td>Cases not taken up Notification</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="notify" checked value="yes">Enable&nbsp;/&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="notify" value="no">Disable
</td>
```

If user click disable button the notification need to be disabled.

Comment: Please add more information to your question

Comment: @Sfili_81 I have a following

Comment: CASES NOT TAKENUP
O.S. No.866/2016 ADM Madurai 01-07-2019
IA No.273/2010 PSJ Madurai 02-07-2019

Comment: If i click disable button the particular need to be disabled.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to visually disable / remove something from the page when the user clicks the 'no' radio button?

Or do you want to submit this form to your back-end and disable future email notifications or something like that?

You should also tell us what you have or haven't tried so far, that will help other people on here figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @nealio82 Yes I want to remove the particular record when the user clicks the 'no' radio button

Comment: @Ajithkumar It's unclear what you want to achieve. What is this record you want to delete. Is it an element in your html? Is it something in your php? Is it an record in a database? Please update your question so we can reproduce your issue (with the minimal amount of code). Also add what you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform this action on client side, using javascript or jquery, meanwhile below is the snippet of javascript you could use.

```
<table>
    <tr> 
            <td id="to_be_disbaled">Cases not taken up Notification</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="notify" checked value="yes" onclick="enable()">Enable&nbsp;/&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="notify" value="no" onclick="disable()">Disable
            </td>        
    </tr>

</table>

<script>

function disable(){
    alert("call disbale")
    document.getElementById("to_be_disbaled").disabled = true;
}
function enable(){
    alert("call enable")
    document.getElementById("to_be_disbaled").disabled = false;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: your question, as asked, has nothing to do with PHP. Your example is pure HTML and most replies you are going to get are going to logically use HTML/CSS and (possibly) Javascript.

Both the vanilla JavaScript and vanilla CSS replies above answer your question as is again without PHP.

If you could give us more information as to what you are going to do with the user's choice once they submit the form we could perhaps provide a more useful PHP-based reply.